# Bteq import taking much time

Tags: teradata

Below teradata query is taking much more time and sitting in delay queue again n again? any prompt help is appreciated

```
/*    FILE IMPORT BTEQ WITH PACK OPTION  */

delete from appl.a;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;


.import FILE=KR.GSED200.LGSALES.txt;

.QUIET ON

.REPEAT * pack 1000

USING

      DAY_NBR (CHAR(6))
     ,LOCN_NBR (CHAR(5))
     ,SLS_TYPE_CD (CHAR(1))
     ,DVSN_371_RETL_SLS_DLR (CHAR(12))
     ,DVSN_471_RETL_SLS_DLR (CHAR(12))
     ,DVSN_571_RETL_SLS_DLR (CHAR(12))
     ,DVSN_671_RETL_SLS_DLR (CHAR(9))


INSERT INTO app.a
(

     DAY_NBR
     ,LOCN_NBR
     ,SLS_TYPE_CD
     ,DVSN_371_RETL_SLS_DLR
     ,DVSN_471_RETL_SLS_DLR
     ,DVSN_571_RETL_SLS_DLR
     ,DVSN_671_RETL_SLS_DLR
)

VALUES

(
     :DAY_NBR
     ,:LOCN_NBR
     ,:SLS_TYPE_CD
     ,trim(:DVSN_371_RETL_SLS_DLR)
     ,trim(:DVSN_471_RETL_SLS_DLR)
     ,trim(:DVSN_571_RETL_SLS_DLR)
     ,trim(:DVSN_671_RETL_SLS_DLR)

);


.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;
.QUIET OFF
.LOGOFF
.QUIT
```

Comment: Either switch to a load utility (TPT) or talk to your DBA.

Comment: what is the number of records you are trying to import ? @Rahul Shivhare

Comment: A query sitting in delayed queue means there are other priority queries ( according to the rules set by DBA on TASM) are active and your query is waiting for the resources. This needs DBA attention or you can submit the request when the usage is low and your query picks up quickly.
Adding to the above, if the amount of data you are loading quite huge, then think about using TPT or FastLoad.